# Bootstrap 3 - Align font-awesome icon inside button vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am trying to align some font-awesome arrow vertically inside two Bootstrap buttons.

Actually both the text and the icons should be vertically aligned in the middle of the button.

If the text inside falls into a single line or wraps in multiple ones the arrow icon should always adjust to the middle of the total height of the button, if that makes sense.

I've been trying to sort this one out for hours now but for the life of me I can't figure this out.

Here's the markup:

```
    <div class="container">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-foo1"><span> this is <br>button<br>one</span><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-foo2"><span>this is button two</span><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></button>
          </div>
</div>
```

and here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9brbD/15/) (**updated**) with what I currently have. Please note that the red background of the icons should touch the edges of the button (top/bottom/right) as opposed to what it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Set both elements to display inline-block and then set the span to take up a percentage of the space. In this case 90% / 10% seems to work good.

```
span {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:90%;
}
```

To remove the padding you can do this: (*probably want to add a some left padding*)

```
.btn-foo1,
.btn-foo2 {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Change display to inline block, and remove right float:

```
.btn-foo1 [class^="icon-"],
.btn-foo2 [class^="icon-"],
.btn-foo1 [class*=" icon-"],
.btn-foo2 [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:24px;
  width:10%;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9brbD/19/

Also I would add a class to the span, instead of using `span {}` use `myClass {}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! True, but the red background still has a padding top and bottom. from the edge of the button and the text is not vertically centered.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer and fiddle to more closely reflect what I think you are going for.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. However, when you resize the container the width:90.1%; does not work really well. i.e. in a responsive situation.

Comment: You could just add 10% width to your icon... See updated fiddle and answer. You may need to tweak it a little still.. But really this should have you close.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I have updated the http://jsfiddle.net/9brbD/21/. When the font-size is big the red background doesn't fit properly. Is basically what I am asking impossible with CSS? Ideally the width of the red block should have fixed width and the blue with the text variable. Is it possible to do this by rearranging the html?